# BeautifulSoup parsing is faster with result.text than with result.content. Why?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

On my machine, using `result.text` is at least five times faster than using `result.content`. Can someone please explain why?

```
def get_information(android_id):
    print "starting request"
    result = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={}".format(android_id))
    c = result.text
    if result.status_code != 200:
        print(c)
        return None
    print "starting parsing"
    only_information = SoupStrainer("div", {"itemprop": True})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "lxml", parse_only=only_information)
    print "starting find"
    version = soup.find("div", {"itemprop": "softwareVersion"})
    print(version.text)
```